# Electron: cannot scroll to bottom of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, electron

I'm trying to make a fake console using electron and I can't seem to be able to scroll on the bottom of the div containing the text, no matter what I try. I have used this code:

```
var d = $('#div1');
d.scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight"));
```

And plenty variants of the code above, both with jQuery and javascript. Do I have a problem because of electron? I just want to scroll to the bottom of the div.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it.

http://lifesweeter21.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-scroll-top-or-bottom-of-document.html

Using this code:

```
    function gobottom(){
var documentHeight=document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
var viewportHeight=window.innerHeight;
window.scrollTo(0,documentHeight-viewportHeight);
}
```

Comment: just what I was looking for!